# Java JSR-303 Bean Validation - implementation comparison

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm looking into adding JSR-303 validation to an application and I'm down to two options:

- [Hibernate validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator)
- [agimatec-validation](http://code.google.com/p/agimatec-validation/)

I'm looking into something lightweight but also complete from the specification point of view.

I'm inclined to use Agimatec, but Hibernate's implementation is "the reference".

Where could I find a comparison of both with advantages/disadvantages of each? Can you share from your experience in case you used both? Or maybe a third alternative if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a comparison of the two..

http://carinae.net/2010/06/benchmarking-hibernate-validator-and-apache-beanvalidation-the-two-jsr-303-implementations/